# TCP/IP, unclear which IP to use to connect to server

Tags: tcpclient, tcp

I am trying to run some TCPIP client and server application. I am new to TCPIP, I neither programmed the server nor the client, but need to obtain data via the client.

The programm (and setup) is the following. I have an application running on one of our servers, which opens a window in XQuartz (locally on my machine, I assume?!). The client is supposed to communicate with the server that is supposed to use the image in displayed in the window to get some data and "send" that to the client.

In the normal configuration, you would run both the server and client on the same machine. Than you would be able to connect to the server using localhost. (I did this in the past and this worked)

However now the application that "provides" the server runs on a server (thus a different machine) so I concluded that I have to connect to something else than localhost. Is that correct? 
What do I have to connect to? The servers IP?

What's confusing me most is the fact, that the window (so the source of the data) is opened on my on machine. So it might be localhost after all?

If I run the client, it cannot connect to neither the servers IP nor to localhost. However, if I try localhost it takes forever until it tells me that it cannot connect while for the server's IP this information pops up instantaneous.

Comment: A *client*  is typically the program you run locally on your computer. A *server*  is the program that the client connects to, it may be anywhere in the world. You most likely connect to many servers every day, at least if you use email or the web. Each email-server you fetch email from is a *server*, each web-server you read (like stackoverflow.com) is a *server*. The email program you use is a *client*, the web-browser you use is a *client*.

Comment: What I'm trying to say, is that the server ip-address you should connect to is the ip-address of the computer where the server-program is running.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, so I did, indeed, try the right thing. So the fact that the client won't connect to the server when using the servers IP-adress should then be linked to some other error rather than using the wrong IP. Thank you!